# How do I launch Python SimpleHTTPServer on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I want to launch Python HTTPServer on heroku. Note that this is no Python framework. The code snippet is attached below. How will I be able to launch this server on Heroku? I am able to run this server on my local machine. But I want it deployed on Heroku. Please provide insights.

Server Code:

```
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver
import threading

PORT = 5001

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.write("Heroku is awesome")

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

try:
    server = ThreadedTCPServer(('', PORT), myHandler)
    print ('Started httpserver on port ' , PORT)
    ip,port = server.server_address
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    allow_reuse_address = True
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('CTRL + C RECEIVED - Shutting down the REST server')
    server.socket.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

When heroku runs your process, it defines the environment variable `PORT` to the internal port you should expose your server on. Your server will then be accessible from the internet on port 80, the default HTTP port.

Python can access environment variables with `os.environ`.

So you can use:
`PORT = environ['PORT']`

`os.envron` docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

You can read more about how Heroku handles ports [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers).

Comment: This doesn't help. used PORT = environ['PORT'] rather than using PORT = 8081. It shows key error at environ['PORT'].

Comment: Are you receiving the error when running on heroku, or when you run it on your local machine?

Comment: I am receiving error when I am running on both heroku and local machine. When I give PORT = 8081 it is at least running on localhost:8081 but when I give PORT = environ['PORT'], it is not working at all.

Comment: On your local machine, the `PORT` environment variable is likely not set, which is likely causing the issues, whereas it is set automatically on the Heroku instance.  You can either test locally using `heroku local` in your shell, or you could use something like `PORT = environ.get('PORT', "8080")` which will return a default when the env var is not found

Comment: That's true. But then when I run the code on heroku, it should technically work. It's building and when I try the command heroku open, it's not loading the static html page cause it can't recognize the port.

Comment: When I run your code, even on localhost, it isn't working. The browser returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.  I believe on line 10 you meant `self.wfile.write(b"Heroku is awesome")`, `self` has no `write` method

Comment: Yeah that's write. I meant self.wfile.write(b"Heroku is awesome"

Comment: Does that fix the issue?

Comment: However is it running on heroku? All I want to do is execute this server on heroku. But when I try running this, it doesn't work.

Comment: No it didn't. Were you able to run this code on heroku?

Comment: So, turns out the problem was your code is not sending the status code.  Adding `self.send_response(200)` and `self.end_headers()` above the bit where your write the response fixes the problem on heroku.  Here is a minimal working example https://hastebin.com/eranotedix.py

Comment: It is working smooth. Thanks to your code. And yeah this answer is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Procfile` with a single line:

```
web: python yourscript.py
```

Comment: The above comment is not working. Because I am defining a port you see. I am opening https://myprojectname.heroku.com but the web page is not loading or it is not printing the output. What's the proper way to make this work?