# Host a python application built on SimpleHTTPRequest on a linux server

Tags: python-3.x, linux, webserver, web-hosting

I have built my own webserver using SimpleHTTPRequestHandler in python. It works as expected on my local and I don't want to use any third-party libraries. If I had to host it on a Linux hosting server and up my web application, is it possible and are there any examples to do so. I am furnishing my code below,

```
from User import User
import json
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

class GetHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

        def do_GET(self):
            urlParts = str(self.path).split("?")
            params = urlParts[0].split("/")
            parsed = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'appplication/json')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps(getattr(eval(params[1]), params[2])()), encoding='utf-8'))
            return
            

        def do_POST(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.data_string = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
            data = json.loads(self.data_string)
            print(data)
            data = '<html><body><h1>POST!</h1></body></html>'
            self.wfile.write(bytes(data, encoding='utf-8'))
            return

Handler=GetHandler

httpd=HTTPServer(("localhost", 8081), Handler)
print("Server started on localhost:8081")
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: You code is incomplete. Where does User come from? Back to the question, you could be setting up a virtual machine and running your Python script there. You really can do it in a lot of ways, but if this is anything more than a one time personal experiment I would recommend you trust a different setup, as described for instance in [HOWTO Use Python in the web](https://docs.python.org/3.0/howto/webservers.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad but yes, it can be done in a multitude of ways.

You need:

1. a domain name
2. an internet facing address
3. an host capable of running python
4. some knowledge of how the web works

Since it can get complicated, I suggest you use a PaaS instead (example: Heroku, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172494/how-do-i-launch-python-simplehttpserver-on-heroku), already answered on SO) to use your code.

IMHO : don't use this code in a production scenario. If this is anything more than a one time personal experiment I would recommend you trust a different setup, as described for instance in [HOWTO Use Python in the web](https://docs.python.org/3.0/howto/webservers.html) or in the [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) .